# Handle a paste event in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, static-methods, paste

I've created a static class numeric Textbox but i wan't to control what the users paste in te textbox. 
For handling paste Event i use textchanged event:

```
        static public void textChanged(EventArgs e, TextBox textbox, double tailleMini, double tailleMaxi, string carNonAutorisé)
    {            
        //Recherche dans la TextBox, la première occurrence de l'expression régulière.
        Match match = Regex.Match(textbox.Text, carNonAutorisé);
        /*Si il y a une Mauvaise occurence:
         *   - On efface le contenu collé
         *   - On prévient l'utilisateur 
         */
        if (match.Success)
        {
            textbox.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Votre copie un ou des caractère(s) non autorisé", "Attention", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        tailleTextBox(textbox, tailleMini, tailleMaxi);
    }
```

In another class i use this static methode like this

```
    private void tbxSigné_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FiltreTbx.textChanged(e, tbxSigné, double.MinValue, double.MaxValue, @"[^\d\,\;\.\-]");
    }
```

What i wan't to do is something like that:

```
  if (match.Success)
    {
        textbox.Text = //Write the text before users paste in the textbox;

    }
```

Anyone have an idea please?

Comment: Is C# 2.0 an actual restriction? The solution with C# 3.0 would be quite a bit more elegant.

Comment: Yes i'm force to use c# 2.0 ...

Comment: I forgot that variable capturing was actually introduced in C# 2, even though lambdas are version 3. I've added a few options you may be able to use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, have you considered using [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) instead? It can handle the character filtering for you.

However, for the sake of this exercise, you could think of a solution along this line. This is the usage:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FiltreTbx.AddTextBoxFilter(tbxSigné,
                               double.MinValue, double.MaxValue,
                               @"[^\d\,\;\.\-]");
}
```

This `AddTextBoxFilter` is a new static method, which you only call once. It will add a TextChanged handler to the `TextBox`. This handler uses a [closure](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx) to store the previous `Text` in the text box.

Your static method gained an extra parameter to pass along this previous text.

```
public class FiltreTbx
{
    public static void AddTextBoxFilter(TextBox textbox,
                                        double tailleMini, double tailleMaxi,
                                        string carNonAutorisé)
    {
        string previousText = textbox.Text;

        textbox.TextChanged +=
            delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 textChanged(e, textbox, tailleMini, tailleMaxi,
                             carNonAutorisé, previousText);
                 previousText = textbox.Text;
            };
    }

    static public void textChanged(EventArgs e, TextBox textbox,
                                   double tailleMini, double tailleMaxi,
                                   string carNonAutorisé, string previousText)
    {
        //Recherche dans la TextBox, la première occurrence de l'expression régulière.
        Match match = Regex.Match(textbox.Text, carNonAutorisé);
        /*Si il y a une Mauvaise occurence:
         *   - On efface le contenu collé
         *   - On prévient l'utilisateur 
         */
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Set the Text back to the value it had after the previous
            // TextChanged event.
            textbox.Text = previousText;
            MessageBox.Show("Votre copie un ou des caractère(s) non autorisé",
                            "Attention", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        tailleTextBox(textbox, tailleMini, tailleMaxi);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what `tailleTextBox` is supposed to do exactly, you did not include that source code, but I suspect it enforces the minimum and maximum values?

### Alternate solution

If you want to handle the Paste operation yourself, before it even happens, you will have to intercept the `WM_PASTE` message to the text box. One way of doing is would be by creating a specialized control:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != WM_PASTE)
        {
            // Handle all other messages normally
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        else
        {
            // Some simplified example code that complete replaces the
            // text box content only if the clipboard contains a valid double.
            // I'll leave improvement of this behavior as an exercise :)
            double value;
            if (double.TryParse(Clipboard.GetText(), out value))
            {
                Text = value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you define the class in your WinForms project, you should be able to drag it onto your form like any other control.

Comment: Thanks!!!!               I'm gonna to use your fisrt solution! I can't use maskedtext box because I work on a project with a lot texbox. And the for the tailleTextBox method your right, it's a method for choose max value and min value.

Comment: And do you have an idea for erase the previousText if the paste it's correct ?

Comment: You cannot erase it, because it has to be already initialized before the paste happens. It's just one extra string per text box, I would not worry about it. If you have a lot of text boxes, creating a specialized control might be more practical, but up to you :)

Comment: Yes, you right! I've finally choose specialized control with your alternate solution and statics method. And thanks again.